# Monitoring Individual Jobs in a Scheduler lets say Quartz

Tags: java, linux, unix, quartz

I have a Quartz Scheduler job which runs 4 cron jobs . How can I monitor individual cron jobs for individual batch run failures ?

Comment: You can have separate log files for each of your cron jobs if you want to monitor them separately. Or you could use a single log file for your cron jobs and the jobs themselves would have a keyword notifying the job name in each line they produce.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad Having a log file wont solve the problem of alerting when any job goes down for any reason

Comment: That need was not mentioned in the question. You could create some database tables which would store cron events and another cron job which would pick them up. Thus you would get information about problems almost real-time.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you try some of the Quartz scheduler monitoring tools? For example, there is [QuartzDesk](https://quartzdesk.com) (I am biased here), [JWatch](https://github.com/royrusso/jwatch) and maybe some other tools.

Here is a simple QuartzDesk notification rule that will alert you (in this case, via email) whenever the execution of any of your jobs fails.

*Sample global (scheduler-wide) execution notification rule*
[image: Sample global (scheduler-wide) execution notification rule]

*Sample notification message template*
[image: Sample notification message template]

*Sample notification message with expanded placeholders*
[image: Sample notification message with expanded placeholders]